# invariant is violated while the variable is it not used in it

Tags: tla+

I`m making first steps with TLA and wrote a simple program, supposed to find some numbers with the given logic (i.e. x1 > x2, x = 5). I did setup it in such way: each step it expects 'random' value in variables.
The problem is: when (in next) I do set p3' \in 0..100
program answers that invariant is violated. but when i do set something like p3' = 0 - it works. Program works with two variables without problems.
Seems question is trivial, but still not clear to me :(. here is my test:

```
EXTENDS Naturals

VARIABLES p1, p2, p3

TypeOK == /\ p1   \in 0..100 
          /\ p2   \in 0..100
          /\ p3   \in 0..100

Init == /\ p1 = 0 
        /\ p2 = 0
        /\ p3 = 0

x1  == /\ p1' \in 0..100 
       /\ p2' \in 0..100
       /\ p3' \in 0..100
                 
Next ==   x1
Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_<<p1, p2, p3>> 

NotSolved ==  ~(    /\ p1 > p2 + 10 
                    /\ p2 = 10)
```

Comment: Are you adding NotSolved as an invariant? Or is it TypeOK that is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two things that both fix the spec:

- writing `p3' \in 0..97` instead of `0..100`
- adding the flag `-maxSetSize 1030301`. `-maxSetSize 1030300` does not work.

Given this behavior, my best hypothesis is that TLC doesn't like it when a state generates more next states than can fit into `maxSetSize`. By default the maxSetSize is 1 million. Without p3, p1' and p2' combinatorically generate 10201 states; `floor(1e6 / 10201) = 98 = Cardinality(0..97)`.

Comment: I originally answered this on the TLA+ google group (https://groups.google.com/g/tlaplus/c/06izRrJQYxw/m/lW5ZS5_SAAAJ). I'm copying the answer here to make it easier for other people to find.